# Applications in xamarin in visual studio 2015 professional

Tags: xamarin

Good morning. I have question. I can do commercial applications in xamarin in small team with visual studio 2015 professional?

Do I need to buy additional licenses?

Thank you in advance for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! 
There is a certain size of company that you have to reach before Xamarin starts costing you money. They write on [their Xamarin page](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs):

*"Any individual developer can use Visual Studio Community to create their own free or paid apps"*

In the same page, they write that you pay either if you have >250 PCs or >$1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue